# run-android stopped working and always fail

Tags: android, react-native

All of a sudden, my react native project stopped working in the android emulator.

every time I run

react-native run-android

i get the message 'Unfortunately, APPNAME has stopped.

My setup files are [here](https://github.com/PolyStyle/ReactNativeMobileClient/tree/master/android).

The app is launched using
/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -n com.selfy/.MainActivity)...

I'm not sure what did happen before the last time it was working just fine. On the iOS simulator, the app runs as usual.

Just to get me started with the debug, what's the usual procedure to debug, when the app doesn't even start on the device? Is there a way to save the error stuck somewhere?

LogCat logs here:

```html
01-04 10:27:34.401  2520  2520 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-04 10:27:34.402  2520  2520 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 10:27:34.403  2520  2520 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-04 10:27:34.423  2520  2520 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
01-04 10:27:34.427  2520  2520 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 10:27:34.440  2520  2520 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 10:27:34.440  2520  2520 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 10:27:34.441  2520  2520 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 10:27:34.448  2520  2520 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-04 10:27:34.456  2520  2520 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 10:27:34.676  2530  2530 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-04 10:27:34.678  2530  2530 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 10:27:34.678  2530  2530 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-04 10:27:34.701  2530  2530 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
01-04 10:27:34.706  2530  2530 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 10:27:34.720  2530  2530 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 10:27:34.720  2530  2530 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 10:27:34.721  2530  2530 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 10:27:34.727  2530  2530 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-04 10:27:34.742  2530  2530 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
01-04 10:27:34.742  2530  2530 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
01-04 10:27:34.989  2541  2541 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-04 10:27:34.990  2541  2541 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 10:27:34.990  2541  2541 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-04 10:27:35.012  2541  2541 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
01-04 10:27:35.015  2541  2541 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 10:27:35.028  2541  2541 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 10:27:35.028  2541  2541 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 10:27:35.028  2541  2541 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 10:27:35.034  2541  2541 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-04 10:27:35.043  1234  1234 I         : free_cache(9402219) avail 469483520
01-04 10:27:36.164  2541  2541 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
01-04 10:27:36.164  2541  2541 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
01-04 10:27:36.376  2553  2553 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-04 10:27:36.378  2553  2553 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 10:27:36.378  2553  2553 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-04 10:27:36.401  2553  2553 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
01-04 10:27:36.406  2553  2553 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 10:27:36.420  2553  2553 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 10:27:36.420  2553  2553 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 10:27:36.420  2553  2553 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 10:27:36.431  2553  2553 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
01-04 10:27:36.723  1480  1492 W art     : Long monitor contention with owner PackageInstaller (1507) at int android.content.res.AssetManager.getStringBlockCount!()(AssetManager.java:-2) waiters=0 in android.content.pm.PackageInstaller$SessionInfo com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerSession.generateInfo() for 282ms
01-04 10:27:36.752  1480  1506 I PackageManager.DexOptimizer: Running dexopt (dex2oat) on: /data/app/vmdl1425441869.tmp/base.apk pkg=com.selfy isa=x86 vmSafeMode=false debuggable=true target-filter=interpret-only oatDir = /data/app/vmdl1425441869.tmp/oat sharedLibraries=null
01-04 10:27:36.764  2564  2564 W dex2oat : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-04 10:27:36.765  2564  2564 W dex2oat : Mismatch between dex2oat instruction set features (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,-ssse3,-sse4.1,-sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,-popcnt) and those of dex2oat executable (ISA: X86 Feature string: smp,ssse3,sse4.1,sse4.2,-avx,-avx2,-lock_add,popcnt) for the command line:
01-04 10:27:36.765  2564  2564 W dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --zip-fd=6 --zip-location=base.apk --oat-fd=7 --oat-location=/data/app/vmdl1425441869.tmp/oat/x86/base.odex --instruction-set=x86 --instruction-set-variant=x86 --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=interpret-only --swap-fd=9 --debuggable
01-04 10:27:36.765  2564  2564 I dex2oat : /system/bin/dex2oat --compiler-filter=interpret-only --debuggable
01-04 10:27:36.765  2564  2564 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-04 10:27:36.929  2564  2566 W dex2oat : Before Android 4.1, method int android.support.v7.widget.ListViewCompat.lookForSelectablePosition(int, boolean) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.ListView
01-04 10:27:36.978  2564  2566 W dex2oat : Before Android 4.1, method boolean com.facebook.share.widget.ShareButtonBase.canShare() would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.widget.TextView
01-04 10:27:36.983  2564  2564 W dex2oat : Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
01-04 10:27:38.944  2564  2564 I dex2oat : dex2oat took 2.179s (threads: 2) arena alloc=280KB (287040B) java alloc=5MB (6023456B) native alloc=8MB (8991224B) free=2MB (3067400B)
01-04 10:27:38.949  1480  1494 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.selfy appid=10054 user=-1: installPackageLI
01-04 10:27:38.962  1480  1506 I PackageManager: Package com.selfy codePath changed from /data/app/com.selfy-1 to /data/app/com.selfy-2; Retaining data and using new
01-04 10:27:38.962  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Code path for com.selfy changing from /data/app/com.selfy-1 to /data/app/com.selfy-2
01-04 10:27:38.962  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Resource path for com.selfy changing from /data/app/com.selfy-1 to /data/app/com.selfy-2
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.htc.launcher.permission.UPDATE_SHORTCUT in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.anddoes.launcher.permission.UPDATE_COUNT in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.majeur.launcher.permission.UPDATE_BADGE in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.CHANGE_BADGE in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.READ_SETTINGS in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.980  1480  1506 W PackageManager: Unknown permission com.huawei.android.launcher.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS in package com.selfy
01-04 10:27:38.996  1480  1506 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Explicit
01-04 10:27:39.014  1480  1506 I art     : Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 51004(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 17(676KB) LOS objects, 23% free, 12MB/16MB, paused 641us total 17.238ms
01-04 10:27:39.018  1234  1234 E         : Couldn't opendir /data/app/vmdl1425441869.tmp: No such file or directory
01-04 10:27:39.022  2553  2553 I art     : System.exit called, status: 0
01-04 10:27:39.022  2553  2553 I AndroidRuntime: VM exiting with result code 0.
01-04 10:27:39.022  1480  1506 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.selfy appid=10054 user=0: pkg removed
01-04 10:27:39.042  1480  1521 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
01-04 10:27:39.057  1480  1521 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
01-04 10:27:39.061  1480  1521 I InputReader: Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010
01-04 10:27:39.061  1897  1897 W ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1385 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 android.content.ContextWrapper.startService:613 com.android.keychain.KeyChainBroadcastReceiver.onReceive:12 android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver:3011
01-04 10:27:39.133  1480  1493 W VoiceInteractionManagerService: no available voice recognition services found for user 0
01-04 10:27:39.133  1480  1493 W LocationProviderProxy-network: Odd, no component found for service com.android.location.service.v3.NetworkLocationProvider
01-04 10:27:39.139  1480  1493 W GeocoderProxy: Odd, no component found for service com.android.location.service.GeocodeProvider
01-04 10:27:39.139  1480  1493 W GeofenceProxy: Odd, no component found for service com.android.location.service.GeofenceProvider
01-04 10:27:39.139  1480  1493 W ActivityRecognitionProxy: Odd, no component found for service com.android.location.service.ActivityRecognitionProvider
01-04 10:27:39.143  1695  1695 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
01-04 10:27:39.146  1695  1695 D CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
01-04 10:27:39.147  1695  1695 D CarrierConfigLoader: mHandler: 9 phoneId: 0
01-04 10:27:39.702  2570  2570 D AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
01-04 10:27:39.703  2570  2570 D AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
01-04 10:27:39.703  2570  2570 E cutils-trace: Error opening trace file: Permission denied (13)
01-04 10:27:39.724  2570  2570 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86_64
01-04 10:27:39.728  2570  2570 D ICU     : No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
01-04 10:27:39.744  2570  2570 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
01-04 10:27:39.744  2570  2570 E android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
01-04 10:27:39.748  2570  2570 I Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
01-04 10:27:39.759  2570  2570 D AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
01-04 10:27:39.765  1480  1591 I ActivityManager: START u0 {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.selfy/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
01-04 10:27:39.774  2570  2570 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 10:27:39.787  1480  1939 I ActivityManager: Start proc 2580:com.selfy/u0a54 for activity com.selfy/.MainActivity
01-04 10:27:39.794  2580  2580 I art     : Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
01-04 10:27:39.795  2580  2580 W art     : Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
01-04 10:27:39.818  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x933 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:39.842  1480  1501 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7ffed95948e0, tid 1501
01-04 10:27:39.881  2580  2595 D NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
01-04 10:27:39.889  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: locked dso store /data/user/0/com.selfy/lib-main
01-04 10:27:39.889  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: deps mismatch on deps store: regenerating
01-04 10:27:39.890  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: so store dirty: regenerating
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libfb.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libfolly_json.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libglog.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libglog_init.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libgnustl_shared.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libicu_common.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libimagepipeline.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libjsc.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreactnativejni.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.923  2580  2580 D ApkSoSource: not allowing consideration of lib/x86/libreactnativejnifb.so: deferring to libdir
01-04 10:27:39.924  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: regenerating DSO store com.facebook.soloader.ApkSoSource
01-04 10:27:39.924  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: starting syncer worker
01-04 10:27:39.939  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.selfy/lib-main (from syncer thread)
01-04 10:27:39.940  2580  2580 V fb-UnpackingSoSource: not releasing dso store lock for /data/user/0/com.selfy/lib-main (syncer thread started)
01-04 10:27:40.009  2580  2580 W unknown:React: Packager connection already open, nooping.
01-04 10:27:40.023  1220  2506 E SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
01-04 10:27:41.021  2580  2610 D         : HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xe36cc700, tid 2610
01-04 10:27:41.021  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.022  1480  1501 I Choreographer: Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-04 10:27:41.038  2580  2610 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 10:27:41.038  2580  2610 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-04 10:27:41.046  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.067  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.095  2580  2610 W gralloc_ranchu: Gralloc pipe failed
01-04 10:27:41.244  1220  1252 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.249  1220  1252 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.257  1480  1501 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.selfy/.MainActivity: +1s483ms
01-04 10:27:41.262  1220  1252 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.394  2580  2580 I art     : Thread[1,tid=2580,Native,Thread*=0xf008b400,peer=0x750cd6f0,"main"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.selfy-2/lib/x86/libfb.so"
01-04 10:27:41.404  1480  1938 W InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@f85b331 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@1a05b66
01-04 10:27:41.410  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTRenderableViewManager
01-04 10:27:41.410  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTGroupShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.411  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTShapeShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.412  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTTextShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.413  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewManager
01-04 10:27:41.414  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.art.ARTSurfaceViewShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.420  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDialogPickerManager
01-04 10:27:41.421  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.uimanager.LayoutShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.421  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.drawer.ReactDrawerLayoutManager
01-04 10:27:41.422  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.picker.ReactDropdownPickerManager
com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager
01-04 10:27:41.437  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.slider.ReactSliderManager$ReactSliderShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.437  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager
01-04 10:27:41.438  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.switchview.ReactSwitchManager$ReactSwitchShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.441  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageViewManager
01-04 10:27:41.442  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.text.frescosupport.FrescoBasedReactTextInlineImageShadowNode
01-04 10:27:41.442  2580  2596 W unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater: Could not find generated setter for class com.facebook.react.views.textinput.ReactTextInputManager
01-04 10:27:41.448  1480  1501 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.selfy) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8079 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102
01-04 10:27:41.583  1480  1501 W AppOps  : Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 10054 pkg com.selfy code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
01-04 10:27:41.792  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: NOTIFICATION CLICKED
01-04 10:27:41.803  1480  1747 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.android.launcher3/com.android.launcher3.Launcher) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2073 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:363 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.notifyAppStopped:389 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.notifyAppStopped:4456 com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.activityStoppedLocked:1252 com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.activityStopped:6873
01-04 10:27:41.848  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: { type: '@@redux/INIT' }
01-04 10:27:41.848  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: { type: '@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_h.k.0.z.2' }
01-04 10:27:41.848  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: { type: '@@redux/INIT' }
01-04 10:27:41.848  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: { type: '@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION_6.p.6.i.j.h' }
01-04 10:27:41.851  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: { type: '@@INIT' }
01-04 10:27:41.852  2580  2615 I ReactNativeJS: { type: '@@INIT' }
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RNPushNotification]
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.selfy, PID: 2580
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Method 'void android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.<init>()' is inaccessible to class 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd' appears in /data/app/com.selfy-2/base.apk)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.zzdo(Unknown Source)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.gms.iid.zzd.<init>(Unknown Source)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.zza(Unknown Source)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID.getInstance(Unknown Source)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService.onHandleIntent(RNPushNotificationRegistrationService.java:22)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:67)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
01-04 10:27:41.863  2580  2621 E AndroidRuntime:  at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
01-04 10:27:41.863  1480  1591 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.selfy/.MainActivity
01-04 10:27:41.869  2580  2580 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
01-04 10:27:41.869  2580  2580 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 2580 SIG: 9
01-04 10:27:41.905  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.907  1480  1526 I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-04 10:27:41.907  1480  1526 D OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
01-04 10:27:41.913  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.917  1240  1472 E FrameworkListener: read() failed (Connection reset by peer)
01-04 10:27:41.917  1480  1520 W InputDispatcher: channel '4042ea7 com.selfy/com.selfy.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
01-04 10:27:41.918  1480  1520 E InputDispatcher: channel '4042ea7 com.selfy/com.selfy.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
01-04 10:27:41.921  1480  1729 D GraphicsStats: Buffer count: 3
01-04 10:27:41.921  1480  1729 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{4042ea7 u0 com.selfy/com.selfy.MainActivity}
01-04 10:27:41.921  1480  1729 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '4042ea7 com.selfy/com.selfy.MainActivity (server)'
01-04 10:27:41.921  1480  1729 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=com.selfy/com.selfy.MainActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:1780 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:688 <bottom of call stack>
01-04 10:27:41.922  1480  1492 I ActivityManager: Process com.selfy (pid 2580) has died
01-04 10:27:41.922  1480  1492 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.selfy/com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService in 1000ms
01-04 10:27:41.923  1220  1536 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:41.978  1480  1591 W ActivityManager: Ignoring remove of inactive process: ProcessRecord{4ef2cd9 0:com.selfy/u0a54}
01-04 10:27:42.042  1220  1529 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:42.055  1220  2506 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:42.071  1220  2506 D gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: format 1 and usage 0x900 imply creation of host color buffer
01-04 10:27:42.165  1480  1495 I WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.selfy) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2014 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:881 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1449 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2478 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2436 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2305 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow:2300 com.android.server.wm.Session.remove:193
01-04 10:27:42.166  1480  1495 W AppOps  : Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
01-04 10:27:42.615  1911  1997 W OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
01-04 10:27:43.786  1480  1552 E TaskPersister: File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
```

Thanks

Comment: I dont have any react experience but does LogCat give you any errors on the emulator?

Comment: please forgive me for my newbness on the android platform, but what is LogCat?

Comment: Logcat is used to view the devices log messages, it will provide you with specific error messages and stack traces. Run `/Users/myusername/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 logcat` to start listening for messages

Comment: Thank you,I've added the stack trace of logcat in the main question

Comment: DId you ever find the issue?

Comment: unfortunately no, I had to create a new react native project, and import the previous code.